# cannot login to appropriate page

Tags: php, mysql

I have created the below login function and called the same at another page as given below. But don't know why it is not working for me.

```
function auth_check_user1($login, $password, $agent )
{
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' WHERE login = "' . $login . '" AND password ="' . $password . '" AND user_category ="' . $agent . '"  LIMIT 1';

  $r = $db->query ($query); 

  if ($db->numrows($r)==1) 
  {
     $logged = TRUE;
  } 
  else  
  {
     $logged = FALSE;
  }
  return $logged;
}


if (auth_check_user1($session->fetch('login'), $session->fetch('password'), $session->fetch('agent')) )
{

   $query= 'SELECT first_name,id FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' WHERE approved = 1 AND login = "' . $session->fetch('login') . '" LIMIT 1';

   $r = $db->query( $query);

   <?php echo URL; ?>/login_user.php"><?php echo $lang['Menu_User_Login']; ?>
   <?php echo URL; ?>/index.php?req=logout"><?php echo $lang['Logout']; ?>

}
```

Comment: Is it giving any errors?

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Does it show a blank screen? An error message? Not let anyone log in? Let everyone log in?

Comment: `$db` is out of scope in your `auth_check_user1()` function. You should be passing it in as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo URL; ?>/login_user.php"><?php echo $lang['Menu_User_Login']; ?>
   <?php echo URL; ?>/index.php?req=logout"><?php echo $lang['Logout']; ?>
```

Why do you have `<?php ?>` inside code ? There should be:

```
echo URL.'/login_user.php">'.$lang['Menu_User_Login'];
echo URL.'/index.php?req=logout">'.$lang['Logout'];
```

And I am not sure about the `>` in your output.. that mess up HTML, if your URL is only URL and not some HTML code

Answer (score 0):

> if ($db->numrows($r)==1) {
>           $logged = TRUE;

Shouldn't it be > num_rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
function auth_check_user1($login, $password, $agent )
{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' WHERE login = "' . $login . '" AND password ="' . $password . '" AND user_category ="' . $agent . '"  LIMIT 1';

    $r = $db->query ($query);   

    if ($db->numrows($r)==1) {
        $logged = TRUE;
    } else {
        $logged = FALSE;
    }
        return $logged;
    }

    if (auth_check_user1($session->fetch('login'), $session->fetch('password'), $session->fetch('agent')) ) {

    $query= 'SELECT first_name,id FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' WHERE approved = 1 AND login = "' . $session->fetch('login') . '" LIMIT 1';

    $r = $db->query( $query);

     echo URL . "/login_user.php" .  $lang['Menu_User_Login'];
     echo URL . "index.php?req=logout" . $lang['Logout'];

}
```

Aside from these edits, I can't speak for your functions, numrows could be incorrect.

Comment: actually I have two such login panels in one website.. but at a time only one is working.